# how do I include header files like list.h, queue.h and vector.h in C++ file?

Tags: c++

I downloaded a sample code and cpp files include header files like list.h, queue.h, and vector.h and if I try to build then I got "fatal error: No such file or directory compilation terminated" I think I should include the path to the system library that has those header files but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Which OS and compiler you are using??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most modern "stock" C++ headers don't have a filename extension.

```
#include <list>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
```

Answer (score 2):

Old examples for old compilers. The correct file names should be `<list>`, `<queue>` and `<vector>` accordingly. Probably some more stuff in the examples will break after you fix it, a wild guess here.

Answer (score 1):

Most compilers have a `-I` command-line option so you can specify additional paths to search for headers:

```
$ CC -I/path/to/headers foo.cpp
```

But the headers you mention are ".h" versions of headers that C++ already provides. You might be reading pre-standard C++, in which case you might not have those headers at all, so messing with the include path will just be a waste of time. You may need to convert that code to use the no-extension header names, like `<list>` and `<vector>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gcc then you can use,

```
g++ -I <include_path> file.cpp
```